# Display menu item in both action bar and menu key

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a menu item in res/menu/mymenu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

</menu>
```

But when I press menu key the menu doesn't appear. It only shows in action bar. Also I tried `android:showAsAction="never"` but that time the item only shows in the menu key screen. I want to display the item both in action bar, and in the screen that shows when I press menu key.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bear in mind that all menu items are displayed only once. You cannot instruct the menu to display a single menu item twice, whether that's once in the overflow, and once in the action bar.

With `android:showAsAction="never"`, you're instructing Android to tuck the menu item away into the overflow menu. (On devices without a hardware menu button, the menu item will display in the action bar overflow. On devices with a hardware menu button, the menu item will display in a pop-up menu from the bottom of the screen, which is also known as the action bar overflow.)

With `android:showAsAction="always"`, you do the opposite; it will always appear in the action bar, whether or not there's enough room.

Although I thoroughly discourage your from taking this approach, strictly answering your question is to provide two menu items: one with mode `never`, the other with mode `always`.

I would instead suggest you reconsider whether you want the item in the overflow menu or not. Consider carefully [Google's recommendations on the action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), and either display it or place it in the overflow--not both. Also bear in mind that different device configurations may allow for more items displayed if there is enough room when using `ifRoom`.

Answer (score 0):

Just duplicate the menu item in `your_menu.xml` with the same title but different id. Then in `onOptionsItemSelected()` use the same code function as where `R.id.action_settingsShown` lead to for the new `R.id.action_settingsHidden`.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settingsShown"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings_dark"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settingsHidden"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings_dark"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
```